# declaring a byte variable

Tags: vb.net, declaration

We can declare a byte variable like this, for hex '88'

```
Dim bytes = New Byte() { &H88 }
```

My case, 88 is assigned to a variable, hexvalue

How to declare the byte with the variable hex value?

```
Dim bytes = New Byte() { &H & hexvalue }
```

the above throws syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

&H is just for defining constants by their hex value, so &H88 is actually 136.

You can use this if you want to cast hex input to a byte ( Long and Int also support Parse, so those are viable as well ):

```
Dim q( ) As Byte = New Byte( ){ Byte.Parse( hexvalue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber ) }
```

And you don't even need the leading &h if you do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Kogitsune's answer is a very good one, if the variable `hexvalue`, in your example, is a string.  If, however, `hexvalue` is a numeric type (`Integer`, `Long`, etc.), you can simply cast the value to a `Byte` with `CType`.  For instance:

```
Dim bytes = New Byte() { CType(hexvalue, Byte) }
```